# Null pointer exception in Google Cloud API

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

I've looked everywhere for the answer to this one.  I'm using google pull taskqueue and adding items to the taskqueue, but when I access the pull queue I get this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:92)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at com.google.api.services.samples.taskqueue.cmdline.TaskQueueSample.getQueue(TaskQueueSample.java:195)
at com.google.api.services.samples.taskqueue.cmdline.TaskQueueSample.run(TaskQueueSample.java:125)
at com.google.api.services.samples.taskqueue.cmdline.TaskQueueSample.main(TaskQueueSample.java:173)
```

So far I've found references to this error, and apparently it was fixed a couple of years ago.  I've tried the suggestions but they don't seem to work.

Comment: I updated the google api and now I'm just getting a 401 Unauthorized message.  Not sure why though.

Comment: I ended up using a service account key instead of oauth and it works.